# How to create Login With My App button

Tags: android, ios, facebook-login

We have created app, Now we need to provide Login With My App Functionality (Same like FB & Google+) in our app.

I want some guidance on that.

I've some idea that how to do it

**IDEA**

1. Create URL scheme for my App
2. So who ever want to use my app login they have to integrate my 
   framework and add URL scheme(but how will i get there app image?)

I need some suggestion for this! where to start, how to implement.